Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS: 'Some' audio stopped working after maintenence updates
After doing a regular (weekly) maintenance update on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, oddly, some of the audio simply stopped working.  What's perplexing to me is that it appears that the only output that broke was anything off of the internet and, the "right" and "left" speaker test in the Sound pop-up in Settings. All else seems to work - system alert sounds, audio from applications like VLC Media Player and OBS Studio, etc.
There are no error messages that I can reckon (not that I necessarily am looking in the right place), and there was nothing upgraded that stood out to me as being decidedly audio related.  I have tried a number of the rudimentary stopping and restarting or resetting Pulseaudio, Pipewire, and so on: to the extent of my limited knowledge.  All to no avail. If someone can give me some insight into this problem, or at point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
Dr. N
